# HTML/CSS Report Design

Tags: html, css

I am writing a report in code and I want to display it as follows:
I have a class called `container` and another class called `child-container`
I want the child container to appear to the right of container
What is included in these classes are either images or text:

Here is a sample of my html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>1. Map Visualisation</h3>
    <br>
    <p>The map displays theÂ percentage of children with exactly one deprivation across various
    countries, the population of each country is also included.
    This visualisation offers a global overview, highlighting geographical patterns and
    pinpointing regions where this issue is most prevalent.
    Users can instantly grasp which countries are facing the most significant challenges and
    observe variations across different parts of the world.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child-container">
    <h3>1. Percentage of children Suffering From Exactly One Deprivation</h3>
    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Map of children suffering">
    </div>
 <div class="container">
    <h3>2. GDP per Capita - 1960</h3>
    <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Scatter Plot">
    </div>
    <div class="child-container">
    <h3>2. Scatter Plot: Time-changing Function</h3>
    <br>
    <p>The scatter plot that explores the correlation between a country&#39;s GDP per capitaÂ andÂ the
    percentage of children suffering from exactly one deprivation.
    Â 
    This visualisation not only illuminates the economic factorsÂ influencing child deprivation
    but alsoÂ challenges assumptions about wealth and well-being.</p>
    </div>
```

I am having really bad problems with position with my css.
Here is my css:

```
body {
padding-left: 20%;
padding-left: 20%;
}
.container img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}

.container {
float: left;
max-width: 40%;
display: inline-block;
}

.child-container {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
max-width: 40%;
text-align: left;
}
.child-container img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

Here's the whole thing as a runnable snippet

```css
body {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-left: 20%;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  max-width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.child-container {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  max-width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
}

.child-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>1. Map Visualisation</h3>
  <br>
  <p>The map displays theÂ percentage of children with exactly one deprivation across various countries, the population of each country is also included. This visualisation offers a global overview, highlighting geographical patterns and pinpointing regions
    where this issue is most prevalent. Users can instantly grasp which countries are facing the most significant challenges and observe variations across different parts of the world.</p>
</div>
<div class="child-container">
  <h3>1. Percentage of children Suffering From Exactly One Deprivation</h3>
  <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Map of children suffering">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h3>2. GDP per Capita - 1960</h3>
  <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Scatter Plot">
</div>
<div class="child-container">
  <h3>2. Scatter Plot: Time-changing Function</h3>
  <br>
  <p>The scatter plot that explores the correlation between a country&#39;s GDP per capitaÂ andÂ the percentage of children suffering from exactly one deprivation. Â  This visualisation not only illuminates the economic factorsÂ influencing child deprivation
    but alsoÂ challenges assumptions about wealth and well-being.</p>
</div>
```

Please feel free to change the either code to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You have to do these two steps to make the `child-container` appear to the `container`'s right.

1. Wrap the two `divs` that must be sided in a single parent `div`.
2. Add `display: flex` to the parent div.

```css
body {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-left: 20%;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10rem;
}

.child-container {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 40%;
  text-align: left;
}

.child-container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="container-left">
        <h3>1. Map Visualisation</h3>
        <br />
        <p>
          The map displays theÂ percentage of children with exactly one
          deprivation across various countries, the population of each country
          is also included. This visualisation offers a global overview,
          highlighting geographical patterns and pinpointing regions where this
          issue is most prevalent. Users can instantly grasp which countries are
          facing the most significant challenges and observe variations across
          different parts of the world.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="child-container">
        <h3>
          1. Percentage of children Suffering From Exactly One Deprivation
        </h3>
        <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Map of children suffering" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This did not work, the next the "container-left" appeared to the right of the previous "container-left"